# I need help, invisible window

Tags: texniccenter, transparency

I was playing with the different options in TeXnicCenter, when I came across the transparency option in the view tab. It lets you adjust the transparency between Adobe Reader and TeXnicCenter, and of course i had to try adjust it to 0%. Now I cant see my TeXnicCenter window...Reopening the program doesnt work. My question is: do I have to reinstall the program or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This question is quite of the edge between on- and off-topic, in my point of view, since it is not directly connected with TeX, rather a technical feature of the editor

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But Tex editor's are on topic. This has been discussed before. Just search for Vim and Emacs related questions.

Comment: Use the keyboard shortcuts Alt+V R to open the transparency window. Then use the left/right arrows to adjust the transparency back to 0% (use the left key).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us the version of TeXnicCenter you use.

With the current version 2.2 there are no tabulator keys defined to open the transparency windows or to change the value.  (The given keys in the comment of werner are no longer working). There are also no commands or keys defined to change the value of the transparency (You can check this by your own in the help menu of TeXnicCenter, viewing "all commands" in "Help keyboard".)

I didn't check if there is a registry entry for the transparency.

**Conclusion:** You can't change the transparency if you can't access the transparency window.  You have to install TeXnicCenter new.

**Hint:** Copy your profile definitions into a `tco` file.  Then you can easy recreate your complete profiles with importing the tco file after your new installation.